# InfluxDB 2.0 has slow write performance with Python client compared to MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, benchmarking, influxdb, influxdb-python

I am new to InfluxDB and I am trying to compare the performance of MariaDB and InfluxDB 2.0. Therefore I perform a benchmark of about 350.000 rows which are stored in a txt file (30mb).

I use ‘executemany’ to write multiple rows into the database when using MariaDB which took about 20 seconds for all rows (using Python).

So, I tried the same with InfluxDB using the Python client, attached are the major steps of how i do it.

```
#Configuring the write api
write_api = client.write_api(write_options=WriteOptions(batch_size=10_000, flush_interval=5_000))

#Creating the Point
p = Point(“Test”).field(“column_1”,value_1).field(“column_2”,value_2) #having 7 fields in total

#Appending the point to create a list
data.append(p)

#Then writing the data as a whole into the database, I do this after collecting 200.000 points (this had the best performance), then I clean the variable “data” to start again
write_api.write(“bucket”, “org”, data)
```

When executing this it takes about 40 seconds which is double the time of MariaDB.

I am stuck with this problem for quite some time now because the documentation suggests that I write it in batches, which I do and in theory it should be faster than MariaDB.

But probably I am missing something

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time to shovel 20MB of anything onto the disk.

`executemany` probably does batching.  (I don't know the details.)

It sounds like InfluxDB does not do as good a job.

To shovel lots of data into a table:

- Given a CSV file, `LOAD DATA INFILE` is the fastest.  But if you have to first create that file, it may not win the race.
- "Batched" `INSERTs` are very fast:  `INSERT ... VALUE (1,11), (2, 22), ...`  For 100 rows, that runs about 10 times as fast as single-row `INSERTs`.  Beyond 100 or so rows, it gets into "diminishing returns".
- Combining separate `INSERTs` into a "transaction" avoids transactional overhead.  (Again there is "diminishing returns".)

There are a hundred packages between the user and the database; InfluXDB is yet another one.  I don't know the details.